# Species Distribution Model in R: Error Messages

Tags: r, maxent

I am running `MaxEnt` in R which is a species distribution model -- I am trying to run a 10 fold x validation on the data but keep getting two error messages:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
   arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 0
```

And the warning message:

```
In mean.default(sapply(e, function(x) { :
   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I'm somewhat new to `R` and don't know where I'm going wrong here -- the columns all have the same number of rows and there are no non-numeric values in the data frame... Thanks for any help/thoughts

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the error? Without code for context, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Here is the section of code throwing these error messages:

Comment: xVal<- subset(KCwoT.Tng, select = c(ag, cent, jor, kliv, traw, silt))
k <- 10
group <- kfold(xVal, k)

e <- list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  train <- xVal[group != i,]
  test <- xVal[group == i,]
  trainx<- train[,2:length(xVal)]
  trainp<- train[,1]
  me <- maxent(trainx,trainp)
  testxp<-test[test[,1] == 1,2:length(xVal)]
  testxa<-test[test[,1] == 0,2:length(xVal)]
  testp <- predict(me, testxp)
  testa <- predict(me, testxa)
  e[[i]] <- evaluate(p=testp, a=testa)
}

Comment: mean(sapply( e, function(x){slot(x, 'auc')} ))
median(sapply( e, function(x){slot(x, 'auc')} ))
mean(sapply( e, function(x){slot(x, 'cor')} ))
median(sapply( e, function(x){slot(x, 'cor')} ))

KCwoT.ME.eval@TPR[match(threshold(KCwoT.ME.eval)[2],KCwoT.ME.eval@t)]
KCwoT.ME.eval@TNR[match(threshold(KCwoT.ME.eval)[2],KCwoT.ME.eval@t)]
KCwoT.ME.eval@CCR[match(threshold(KCwoT.ME.eval)[2],KCwoT.ME.eval@t)]

Comment: xVal<- subset(KCwoT.Tng, select = c(ag, cent, jor, kliv, traw, silt))
k <- 10
group <- kfold(xVal, k)

e <- list()
for (i in 1:k) {
  train <- xVal[group != i,]
  test <- xVal[group == i,]
  trainx<- train[,2:length(xVal)]
  trainp<- train[,1]
  me <- maxent(trainx,trainp)
  testxp<-test[test[,1] == 1,2:length(xVal)]
  testxa<-test[test[,1] == 0,2:length(xVal)]
  testp <- predict(me, testxp)
  testa <- predict(me, testxa)
  e[[i]] <- evaluate(p=testp, a=testa)
}

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code using code tags. Also, you'll need to include the data used.

Comment: Thanks so much- I'm new to this site and using tags but think I can figure it out. Looks like I just upload the R script and .csv files and add a tag

Comment: I'm sorry can anyone help direct me how to upload files or post an MCVE? I created an example R script and input file (.csv) and made sure it reproduces the same problem I'm having. However I can't figure out how to make that available for folks to see it?....

Comment: The link I provided in my first comment explains how to post a MCVE. You can edit your original post to add your code and add your example data using `dput` to avoid people having to download a file.